# How to fetch value from select tag in rails2?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

How to fetch the value from the select tag and how can display that selected value in pdf page when click on generate pdf. But the value i using to select is from different model

```
<%= select_tag 'header',options_from_collection_for_select(@reciept_header, 'id', 'receipt_mainheader'), :include_blank => true %>
```

Comment: @reciept_header have single element or multiple

Comment: Here it needs to use f.select because i am use select option in form

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to send this value to another action, where you will generate pdf. You can wrap this select in form and submit it, or use ajax to send select value in another action, and generate/download pdf file asynchronously